# I there a "correct" way for the spring batch partitioner kick off child steps while still creating partitions?

Tags: spring-batch

The partition contract builds all of the partition execution contexts before returning. With extremely large datasets, you in spending a large amount of time waiting on the partitioner to return.

```
@Override
public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
    Map<String, ExecutionContext> out = new LinkedHashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();
    ... stuff to create execution contexts ...
    return out;
}
```

Is there a model built into spring batch which allows the partitions to be fired off to the slave processes as soon as they are identified by the partitioner, instead of waiting for all of the partition contexts to be returned?

The result I am looking for i: Even if it takes my partitioner 15 minutes to return, the remote steps will be queued to as soon as they are generated, instead of waiting 15 minutes for all of the partition contexts to be generated before starting to work

Comment: Well you should look at why the partitioner taking 15 min..

Comment: It's not taking 15 minutes yet, but I can forsee a situation where the simple data volume can take 15 minutes to generate .... LOTS of partitions, and they are not generated instantaneously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a model built into spring batch which allows the partitions to be fired off to the slave processes as soon as they are identified by the partitioner, instead of waiting for all of the partition contexts to be returned?

This is not possible. The partitioner should finish all the partitioning process before workers can start working on partitions.